# How much detail do we want in our questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

There are some questions with little specifics:

The question is being used, as it is an easy example:

[How would I deal with a choking cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/351/how-would-i-deal-with-a-choking-cat)

- I am a little uneasy about questions being allowed that are too broad, is there future more specific questions are at risk of becoming duplicates.

Eg: If my cat has been eating [cooked chicken bones] or [dry food]
I came into the room and the cat was choking, I didn't see if he'd been eating

- If so, how do we handle duplication?
- The other issue is, are the questions  generic.

The issue with a pet site is we are dealing with potential dangers. Dogs breed and size, snake type, etc a few examples of details we need to answer questions well.

[What age of snake is best for a pet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-age-of-snake-is-best-for-a-pet)

> This question appears to be off-topic because it does not give enough detail to give a good answer, given that snakes are a specialised pet and potentially dangerous, I am reluctant to answer this without details of the snake type you are referring to

Do we want such generic questions?

Answer (score 2):

Questions that are too generic are of limited usefulness; in an attempt to answer a vague, what-if scenario with no concrete information, all we can do is write vague, speculative answers.  That's already easy to find; we will not make the Internet a better place by hosting such questions.

In addition, I suspect they will drive away the experts we seek, a problem I've seen on other sites.

There's a reason that the standard close reasons include "too broad" and "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 0):

Actually the amount of content in a question does not really matter. The question should have all of the following:

- A clear, specific explanation
- A narrow enough subject to answer (not too broad), but not too narrow to not be useful
- Well formatted
- Any details that help the question have the above 3.

So a question may have 3 lines, or 3 paragraphs, it all goes down to whether your question is useful and clear.

Comment: I guess the question is, step 4.. to encourage people with step 4 and where do we want to draw the line

Comment: @Skippy: Very simply, we don't. A 5 words question can't possibly good because it's not a clear, specific explanation. A 10 paragraph wall of text cannot be a clear specific explanation either (it may be specific, but it's not clear). Both would probably be too broad and too narrow respectively too. So the hard limit on post length shouldn't exist in my opinion. We on [anime.se] don't limit it, and we're doing pretty well.

Comment: @Skippy: Yes, those definitely lack detail. "How to prevent my dog bad breath" is not enough. What does he eat? What breed is he? Does he like to eat/drink weird things? (for example), the others lack similar detail.