# For generic "health troubleshooting" questions, what to do with specific new observations?

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

This question is about a general case, but I'm not sure how to explain it so I'll just give a specific example.

1. I asked [Initial steps to correct cat's excessive drooling](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/16406) (see edit rev 1 if it's changed after I post this).
2. I later made additional observations, some in response to comments, but some potentially big ones on my own.
3. I framed those as an answer and [posted them](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/16414/987). In my mind this was an answer to my specific case (definitely going to the vet), but still not an answer to the general question (initial steps anybody may want to take to diagnose and correct cat drooling at home) -- which I'd handle by posting as an answer but leaving it unaccepted.

Now I'm wondering (prompted by [this comment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16406/initial-steps-to-correct-cats-excessive-drooling/16417#comment21254_16414)) what to do: Edit all that info back into the question, or leave it generic.

Edit Question:

- Pro: More specific to my case, may get me answers more relevant to *my* situation.
- Con: Kills the generic-ness of the question, may not help other readers as much.
- Con: [May invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) ([see also](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/editing-answered-questions-to-alter-the-original-meaning)).

Leave It:

- Pro: I find great value in questions that are generic (but not vague) that can help other people, plus I specifically want to see the knowledge base of *this* site increase (although, [related discussion here](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/120/987)).
- Pro: Doesn't invalidate any answers.
- Pro: There's always the possibility that another reader may have the exact same specific situation.
- Con: I may be missing out on valuable answers specific to my case.

What should I do with the above question? More importantly, what should I do with questions like this in general, which aren't an uncommon occurrence for me?

Or does nobody care (if not, I'm just going to edit it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with editing the question to reflect an update in information, the meat of the question remains generically useful. Your answer, to be really honest, wasn't one with respect to the original and as a result triggered some flagging. Why? Because it really read like a conversational continuance.

Comment: I found [this semi-related topic](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/a/25/65217) that gives a bit of guidance as well. It's related to the fundamental reasons I asked this meta question (which I did not state, but probably should have). Also I do appreciate your edit to my main question, I rolled it back simply because it was not the form I wanted it to be in. I will edit the information in smoothly as soon as I have the time.